# Search for specific data attribute in divs and return the matches number

Tags: javascript, html, count

I have 4 buttons and 10 divs. Each div has a data-id-cat attribute equal to a number from 1-3. All I'm trying to achieve is to count how many divs have data-id-cat='1', how many = '2' and so on and print the result as a text inside the buttons.

e.g. If I have 4 divs with the atrribute data-id-cat='2', I want to print out 4.

I tried to create an empty array, and for each match, to push the match into the array, then return the array length. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
allCategories.forEach(cat => {
    if(cat.getAttribute('data-id-cat') === '1') {
        countArray.push(cat)
        projectNumber[1].textContent = countArray.length
    } else if(cat.getAttribute('data-id-cat') === '2') {
        countArray.push(cat)
        projectNumber[2].textContent = countArray.length
    } else if(cat.getAttribute('data-id-cat') === '3') {
        countArray.push(cat)
        projectNumber[3].textContent = countArray.length 
    } else {
        projectNumber[0].textContent = allCategories.length
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The browser will happily count them for you:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let n = 1; n <= 3; ++n) {
    const count = document.querySelector(`div[data-id-cat="${n}"]`).length;
    sum += count;
    projectNumber[n].textContent = count;
}
projectNumber[0].textContent = sum;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce to an object where the key is the id-cat value and the value is an incremented count.

```js
const countCat = () => {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-id-cat]")].reduce((ob, el) => {
    const c = el.dataset.idCat;
    ob[c] |= 0;
    ob[c] += 1;
    return ob;
  }, {});
}


console.log(countCat())
```

```html
<div data-id-cat="3"></div>
<div data-id-cat="1"></div>
<div data-id-cat="2"></div>
<div data-id-cat="3"></div>
<div data-id-cat="1"></div>
<div data-id-cat="1"></div>
<div data-id-cat="1"></div>
```